# Can anyone identify this bird?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

[image]

Can anyone identify this bird: it looks like a zebra finch but they are not native to UK  are they?

Photo taken from my garden in Shoreham, West Sussex on 16/8/2014.

Comment: We found a female exactly like this today in North Hertfordshire - hopping around eating seeds on a stony path between fields.

Answer (score 17):

This looks pretty much like a female zebra finch to me (the male have a more prominent feather pattern). See this picture:

[image]

These birds are not native in Europe, this is correct. But it is always possible that birds escape captivity (or are released) and the live in countries where they originally not belong. I think this is the case with the zebra finch here. Since the birds are able to live in a pretty broad range of habitats, they can also survive in England.

According to this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_non-native_birds_of_Great_Britain) page (thanks to @Orethrephes) zebra finches which escaped from captivity are quite common in Britain although they usually not survive for long.

Comment: Looks like there's a note about feral Zebra Finches in the UK here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_non-native_birds_of_Great_Britain

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Thanks for the notification.

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted